# Angular2 ngIf not updating after file upload (with ng2-file-upload)

Tags: angular

I want to make the upload panel hidden automatically after upload complete so i have the following code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'upload-layer',
    template: `<div *ngIf="showUploadLayer">
        <!-- ...(some inputs and buttons here)... -->
</div>`,
    directives: [FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES]
})


export class UploadPanel {

    public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: URL });

    showUploadLayer : boolean = false;

    constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){

        this.uploader.onCompleteAll = function(){
            this.showUploadLayer = false;
            console.log("onCompleteAll");  // this one get called correctly.
            ref.detectChanges();           // try forcing a check here but still not updated
        };
    }
}
```

The onCompleteAll() is called but the div element with ngIf condition is still visible even I set the value to false. 
I searched about how to force a check on change and added detectChanges() but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `function ()` if you want `this` to refer to the current class.

```
this.uploader.onCompleteAll = function(){
```

should be

```
this.uploader.onCompleteAll = () => {
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions